# "drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]" error on Virtual Box Ubuntu, with windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox

I've tried multiple solutions I've seen after looking through different threads with this same error, but I'm still not finding anything that will help me.

After installing ubuntu on the VirtualBox, this appears:

```
/dev/sda3: recovering journal
/dev/sda3: clean, 213711/622592 files, 2147681/2489344 blocks
[    25.207447] [drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message.
```

I've tried:

- Giving it more memory to work with (up to half of my RAM, so 4gbs)
- Reinstalling Ubuntu (about three times)
- Changing the graphics controller to VBoxVGA (didn't give the same text as above, but didn't boot either)
- Changing the video memory up to 128mb
- Unchecking the floppy disk in the boot order, and also both unchecking and moving it to the bottom
- adding nomodeset in kernel boot
- searching for "Attempting fall back to NEM" in the vm logs but is isn't there

I have made sure virtualization is enabled in the startup menu and that it has also been enabled in Windows itself. Please help.

NOTE: there's another question that is similar to this which has `drm:vmw_host_log` but mine consist of `printf` instead of `log`.

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem? I am experiencing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a faulty instance in /etc/fstab. I loaded a image into the system and it got into the fstab file. I removed the line and it is working again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).